# JVM does not work as expected with JNI C++ code containing a class named "Node"

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Myself and some teammates have been unable to understand why the following snippet of code will not give the correct output when using JVMs versions 1.6u23 through 1.6u31 (the latest as of this posting).  This code snippet represents a simplification of a larger problem:

UPDATE:  Modified the example slightly to put focus on the issue that "virtual_function()" does not seem to get called.

UPDATE:  Simplified the example even more based on comments to-date.

NodeTester.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>

class Node {
  public:
    Node () :m_counter(0) {}
    virtual ~Node () {}

    virtual void virtual_function () {
      m_counter += 10;
    }

    void non_virtual_function () {
      m_counter += 1;
    }

    int get_counter () {
      return m_counter;
    }

  private:
    int m_counter;

};

extern "C" {
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NodeTester_testNode (JNIEnv *jni_env_rptr, 
                                                   jclass java_class) {
    Node *node_rptr = new Node();
    node_rptr->non_virtual_function();
    node_rptr->virtual_function();

    std::cout << node_rptr->get_counter() << std::endl;

    delete node_rptr;
  }
}
```

NodeTester.java:

```
public class NodeTester {
  public static native void testNode ();

  static {
    System.loadLibrary("nodetester");
  }

  public static final void main (String[] args) {
    NodeTester.testNode();
  }
}
```

expected output:

```
11
```

actual output with JVM 1.6u23 through 1.6u31:

```
1
```

It seems like the JVM is incorrectly constructing the "Node" object within JNI; although it's possible that this code has something incorrect about its use of JNI.  When the class "Node" gets more functionality added to it (e.g. more attributes, additional virtual and non-virtual operations), we can cause a segmentation fault, rather than just incorrect output.  We're compiling the cpp code into a RedHat linux 64-bit shared object library using g++, and running the java code with the 64-bit Server VM.  Note that on JVMs 1.6u20 through 1.6u22, this produces expected output.  I haven't tried any earlier versions.

We've decided to put a bounty on this question!  Here's more information on what we already know:

- JVMs 1.6u22 (and prior) produce expected results
- Renaming "Node" or putting it in a namespace produces expected results
- Allocating a "Node" object on the stack instead of the heap in the JNI function produces expected results
- There are no issues with non-virtual components of the class "Node"

Unfortunately for us, none of these items lead to viable solutions - the "larger problem" I alluded to was that we're dealing with a large, existing code base with a C++ class named "Node", which we need to access via JNI.  We also tried several g++ and javac compiler options, and several JVM options, to no avail (although if someone stumbles on one that actually yields expected results, this would be an acceptable solution).

Comment: So, I haven't done any C++ in over ten years, so I can't spot the problem, but I compiled the shared object on Ubuntu, and ran the Java program. I'm using the sun/oracle jdk 1.6.0_26-b03

I can verify that I get the same output that you do, and that if I allocate a Node object on the stack instead of the heap, then I get the expected output from the virtual method.

I'll be very interested to see what the solution is.

Comment: OK - that's good to know!  We're using RedHat (forgot to mention that in my original post).  I feel less crazy now.  Still a little crazy :-)

Comment: Have you tried explicitly flushing cout? The problem seems to be C++ rather than JNI as you get into the method without any problem.

Comment: Your example works fine for me using openJDK (IcedTea6 1.10) and g++ version 4.5.2

Comment: Just tried it on my university machine which runs CentOS (derived from RedHat), and which has uses Sun java jdk 1.6.0_21, and I still haven't been able to reproduce your problem (this time with g++ version 4.1.2). Do you compile with -Wall?

Comment: This would seem to be a JVM issue only insofar as the context and environment that the VM provides.  Are the different VM versions pulling in the same set/versions of shared libraries?

Comment: I'm not sure how to manually get a VM dump (which includes loaded shared libraries), but you can certainly get one if you force a segfault in your native code.

Comment: @Tom Class `Base` in your code snippet is redundant. The described behavior is reproduced with any `virtual` method, not necessarily overriden. At least with Sun Java 1.6.0_26 and GCC 4.5.5 on 32-bit Debian.

Comment: did you raise a bug report?  it would be good to link to it here so people can follow this in future?  thanks (+sorry if i've missed it somewhere in the comments).

Comment: @andrewcooke I did (through bugreport.sun.com), however my submission is still at the "internal review" stage.  It's been a couple months - I posted the question here thinking that we had obvious bogus code and that the folks at Oracle had dismissed our bug report as trivial.  If I get an assigned ID I'll update the question - good thought!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, this is not a perfect answer, but if we have nothing better, the following may help. As explained a bit in the other comments, the crux of the problem lies in two distinct C++ classes both named `Node` in the global namespace, one from OpenJDK or SunJDK 1.6u23 and up on RedHat Linux (at least) and another from another library, both of which need to have their symbols shared with other libraries. To get our symbols loaded before the JDK, we may set the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, by calling e.g.:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libTheNodeTester.so java ...
```

But this may crash the JDK, if it actually starts using our symbols as if it were the ones from its libraries...

Comment: Further comment:  we now believe this to be a JVM bug (and I've filed a bug report).  Any class written to support execution of the JVM ought *not* be in the global namespace (or, not loaded dynamically with the "RTLD_GLOBAL" flag).  Arguably, our project should not have classes in the global namespace either, but that's a topic left to the interested reader ;-)

Comment: @Chook thanks, and kudos to you for pointing this out! I'd be glad to shift you 25 points...! is it actually possible?

Comment: Your goodwill is enough :) There isn't (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users)

Comment: We have run into a similar issue and searching turned up this question.  Can you provide information about the bug report you said was filed? I don't see anything related to this at http://bugs.sun.com.  Does Oracle have a new bug DB?

Answer (score 6):

By looking at the HotSpot code there is a node.hpp/node.cpp that declares a node class without a namespace. 
Perhaps there is a collision with the pure virtual functions. 
 
I don't have enough VM knowledge to dig any further...

Comment: Sounds promising - some of the stacks we've seen at problem sites have "node.cpp" showing up.  But what can we do?  There shouldn't be any collision, right, as long as no code units #include both class definitions?

Comment: That gave me an idea. Declaring your Node class starting this way: `class __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))) Node : public Base {` actually works! Would this be a good enough workaround??

Comment: There will be a collision if the hotspot library is loaded with an effective RTLD_GLOBAL option, so the dynamic symbol for the class will clash with yours (see the man page for dlopen).  Run without hotspot to see if hotspot loading is actually the issue, then you can figure out how to effect changes to the symbol load order.

Comment: @SamuelAudet Good idea!  I tried this, and verified that it does work, but I've been unable to make this solution work outside of the example above.  I simplified the example here for brevity, but in reality we also need to re-use "Node" in other c++ modules.  Hiding its visibility prevents that possibility.  This is a great comment though, as I was unaware of this capability.

Comment: @technomage Can you clarify what you mean by "Run without hotspot"?  Do you mean run with a different JVM (like JRockit, or OpenJDK), or do you mean something else?  I suspect you're correct about the library loading, but it's unclear what we can do to work around it.  FWIW, I found an item called 'vtable for Node' within this .so in JDK 1.6u23:  'jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so' - this symbol was not in JDK 1.6u22!

Comment: @Tom Yeah, I think we're out of luck then because the JDK also wants to share that symbol too, i.e.: It becomes very angry when we set `LD_PRELOAD=libYourNodeTester.so`... Since this is apparently new with 1.6u23, I'd file a bug report presto :)

Comment: @SamuelAudet I was also unfamiliar with the LD_PRELOAD environment variable; this at least gives us something to go on.  My JVM didn't seem angry (this action corrected the output), although the test program is not really exercising the JVM, so this will probably not be viable).  Do me a favor, though and post your suggestions in an answer; if we don't get a better lead we'll award you the bounty (and thanks to Samuel and everyone else for the suggestions - keep 'em coming).  I filed a bug report some time ago, but never got a response (I'm sure I'm at the bottom of a very long list :-)

Comment: @Tom sorry, I was conflating hotspot with JIT; apparently the Node declaration is part of the JVM (hotspot).

Answer (score 2):

> It seems like the JVM is incorrectly constructing the "Node" object
>   within JNI

Be clear. The JVM doesn't construct the "Node" object at all. The C++ runtime system does that.

I have used tons of C++ within JNI without any problems other than those I caused.

The first thing that comes to mind is that you aren't checking the result of the 'new' operator for null. That won't affect the non-virtual function, it will just see 'this', which you aren't using, as null, but it will prevent despatching of the virtual function, as the indirection via the vtable will seg-fault.

Why it would be null is another question ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I'm pretty sure the "new" returns a valid address (I remember checking in the debugger), but didn't put that extra check in my test program (although I'll double-check when I get back to work Monday, and I may update the code sample above).  My thinking was, if there was a problem with allocating the memory, I would've seen a "bad_alloc" exception, not a "null" return.  But it doesn't hurt to be defensive; it might even be a good clue as to what's really happening  :-)

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, in the context of the "larger problem" Tom mentions, the _only_ class we've encountered this problem with is `Node` (and renaming our `Node` class gets around the problem).  Note I'm a teammate of Tom's so I'm quite interested as well!

Comment: @Rob In that case, if you have a name clash, putting Node into its own namespace should also work, and might give you a viable option. Also you don't need the extern "C" {} thing aroud the JNI method definition as long as you #include the generated .h file in that .c/.cpp file.

Comment: @EJP  Unfortunately, neither renaming the class, nor putting it in a namespace, are viable options for us.  We might put a bounty on this, so I'm going to edit the question and clarify what we've tried so far.

Comment: "The first thing that comes to mind is that you aren't checking the result of the 'new' operator for null"  There is no point checking the pointer for NULL as it can never be NULL. Failure is indicated by throwing a std::bad_alloc exception

Answer (score 1):

For kicks, try flushing stdout and stderr before you exit the native code. I'm thinking maybe the JVM is exiting with data in some output buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I've since updated the example to more clearly identify the issue.  It's not that the output is lost, it's that the "base_function()" call doesn't actually get executed (bizarre!)  Take another look when you get a chance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a wrapper layer in native code? i.e. write a C++ class to proxy the Node class and call that from java instead of calling Node directly.

In the wrapper you can namespace the imports to avoid ambiguity (http://www.glenmccl.com/ns_comp.htm, for example).

Comment: Good suggestion!  Unfortunately, this is not feasible for our real code base.  Two issues with creating a Wrapper are 1)  the real Node class in our system has many methods and is part of a hierarchy, and the Wrapper would need to reflect this (and keep up with changes), and 2)  there are some other C++ classes that already use Node, for which we also need JNI access - we'd have to update these C++ classes to use the Wrapper instead.

Comment: You can proxy by sub-classing, of course. You only need to proxy in those places where the class is called over JNI (or passed over JNI) - do you control all those points? (for non JNI interactions you can build modules without any JNI linking)

Comment: Proxy by sub-class would help with my first concern, but (unless we're misunderstanding each other) not my second. In our real-world code, we have many C++ classes which already use Node (e.g. `NodeUser`). If I have JNI access to `NodeUser`, and `NodeUser` uses `Node`, I get broken behavior.  Even if I have a `NodeWrapper`, I'd have to find all the classes like `NodeUser` and change them to use `NodeWrapper` instead of `Node`; at that point we might as well rename `Node`, since we're updating references anyway. I hope this makes sense, but appreciate the ideas! :-)